# SparkSubmit can run locally?

Tags: pyspark, spark-submit

when I run below code using the following command

> spark-submit prepiadstream_sample.py --master local[3] --name
> prepiadstream_sample --num-executors 5 --executor-memory 5g
> --driver-memory 5g

I found configuration printed out in the code return the deploy mode as client although I run it locally in Spark submit, shouldn;t spark use the coniguration the command line

> **spark.master    yarn**
>
> **spark.submit.deployMode  client**

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
import time
from pyspark.sql import Row


print("Creating Spark Session")

spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .getOrCreate()

<b> print(spark.sparkContext.getConf()) </b>
```

Comment: can you attach a full log so that we can help you to proceed further?? since spark logs are hard to debug with the comments without attaching logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the order of the arguments. In order my applicaton reads my arguments I should pass all spark configuration arguments **before the application name** otherwise the application will use the **default configuration** of spark. Command need to be sent as follows:

```
spark-submit  --master local[3] --name applicationstream_sample \
--num-executors 5 --executor-memory 5g \
--driver-memory 5g applicationstream_sample.py
```

We can find ways of writing the command properly at following [Spark Submitting](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) docuemntation and notice where they set the application name in their commanfd

Answer (score 0):

Typically you use a spark-submit in production mode. Submitting your spark job allows to set specific options optimized to your environment. the --deploy-mode is used to specify where to run the spark application driver program. If in client mode, the driver runs locally i.e. the machine where you are running your spark submit. It should be used for debugging purposes. Note that the executors run on different machines.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).